# dart dartdap exception when parsing search result

Tags: active-directory, ldap, dart

I'm using the dartdap library to connect to an LDAP server on Win 2008. The bind operation works fine. As soon as I perform any search I get an exception while the result is parsed by dartdap.

```
Exception while processing message. Exception RangeError: Value not in range (158)
```

The stack trace points here:

```
package:dartdap/src/connection/connection_manager.dart:297:21
```

Here is the code I use:

```dart
var filter = Filter.substring("CN=ma*");
var attrs = ["dn", "cn", "objectClass"];
LDAPConfiguration ldapConfig = new LDAPConfiguration("ldap.yaml","default");
LDAPConnection ldap;
ldapConfig.getConnection(false).then((LDAPConnection ldap){
  ldap.bind(/*bindDN*/"CN=CP LDAP,OU=Contract Program,DC=mydomain,DC=de",/*password*/"xxxxx").then((_){
    ldap.search("DC=mydomain,DC=de", filter, attrs).stream.forEach((item)=>print(item)).catchError((err) =>print(err));
  }).catchError((err)=>print(err));    
}).catchError((err)=>print(err));
```

For my project I need to authenticate users using data from an Active Directory. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you filed an issue with the dartdap project?

Comment: I have just now. [link](https://github.com/wstrange/dartdap/issues/1)